# How to Convert keynote file to PDF file using php?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

Is there any way to convert keynote file to PDF file using PHP code?
I need any PHP code or Plugin or any command for the conversion.

Comment: Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: You need to do some proper research and make some attempts. SO is for when you're running into _specific_ issues with your _existing_ code. We're not here to find or write code for you.

Comment: i have found api for this. Reference link : https://cloudconvert.com/api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use api code of https://cloudconvert.com/ for convert file.

Comment: You should remove this question instead of answering it, since it's, as already stated, off-topic for this site.